# Flash/ActionScript - Use .mp3 file in library in a movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript, mp3

I've imported a mp3 file into the library and made an actionscript class, but i can't access is in a movieclip.

EDIT: I'm using Adobe AIR, because i want to compile it as an Android Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `AS Linkage` for your sound (in library panel)

[image]

then paste this code in your movieClip (first keyframe)

```
var snd:Snd=new Snd();
snd.play();
```

hope it helps

Comment: I made it like this, but you can't use the sound inside a movieclip :/

Comment: Oh, found the error. I used the same instance name for the sound as the button has... thanks anyway^^

Comment: it's a common mistake! glad to know that your problem was solved :)